# How do you catch Django rest non_field_errors in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Action.js login function is as follows:

```
export const auth = (username, password) => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authStart());
    const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      };

    const authData = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        returnSecureToken: true
    }

    axios.post("http://localhost:4000/scripts/auth/login/", authData, config)
        .then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
            localStorage.setItem('userId', response.data.user.id);
            dispatch(authLoginSuccess(response.data.token, response.data.user.id));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch(authFail(err))
        })
}
```

}

Django Rest return following detail upon bad credentials:

```
{
"non_field_errors": [
    "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
]
```

}

But when I am logging the error to console, I don't see any fields like non_field_errors. The err object has the following data as shown by redux dev tools:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (createError.js:17)
at settle (settle.js:19)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
```

How to get this message from API response?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I got it !!!

err.response has the actual details

```
console.log(err.response)
```